# Production functions total cost

Tags: functions, economics, applications

Production function is: $f(L,M)=L^{1/2}M^{1/2}$. L is the number of units of labour, M of machines used. Cost of labour is 9 per unit, whereas the cost of machine is 81 per unit. Total cost of producing 10 units of output will be:

a) 270

b) 90

**c) 135**

d) 450

e) non of the above

Why its is 135? I completely do not get it. What is the proper method?

Comment: Are you sure you typed everything correctly?

Comment: maybe the answers are wrong, i do not know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The production function states the quantity that a firm can produce. So if it produces $10$ units:

$$10=f(L,M)=L^{1/2}M^{1/2}$$

Hence:

$$100=LM$$

$$\frac{100}{L}=M$$

We know the cost will be:

$$C=9L+81M$$

$$=9L+\frac{8100}{L}$$

Minimizing this using standard procedures $C'(L)=0$.. gives $L=30$ $C=540$ so I think you typed something wrong.

I have reason to believe that the actual production function is:

$$f(L,M)=4L^{1/2}M^{1/2}$$